# How can I check for the existence of wikldcard strings in a list of multiple strings?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have the bash command

```
git branch --format='%(refname:short)\\EL' --contains > branchoutputs.txt || git rev-parse HEAD
```

Where the output might look like this:

```
develop\\EL
feat/some-feature\\EL
feat/another-thing\\EL
someName/another-branch-name\\EL
```

How can I make that at least one of these conditions is true?

- Match `develop\\EL`
- Match `feat/*\\EL`

Otherwise return false basically.

Comment: You may find what you need by reading [the `man` page for `grep`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep).

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, however this command command might help:

`grep -E ^(develop|feat\/.*)\\\\EL$`

You may need to add more options, such as `-q` or `--quiet` if you do not want `grep` to write errors and/or matching lines to standard output. As suggested by @jim-l, consult your local manual for more information (i.e `man grep` or `info grep`).